# Linux gvim visual mode cursor - avoid newline selection

Tags: visual-mode, highlight

When I enter in visual-mode and I want to delete a block of text before the newline character (only visible if selected/highlighted in visual-mode), I accidentally always select the newline character also, making the line below to *move up*.

Is there a way to make the visual-mode cursor to discard the newline selection ?

I took a look into the help but I think I did not found anything useful for my problem..

I could use the `set list` option so to see the newline character (red $)

[image]

But I don't want to use the `set list` neither accidentally select the newline character(0xa).

**EDIT**

I can achieve this behavior using evim, but of course I don't want to use evim since I loose other modes.
If this is possible in evim, I understand it's possible also in gvim.

Comment: How do you "accidentally" select the carriage return?

Comment: Yes sorry I get totally confused. It's late night here...

Comment: I suppose you delete the selected text using `d`? How about if you delete using `x` ?

Comment: Using `d` or `x` behaves the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using

```
:set selection=exclusive
```

This is the option that controls this behavior.
For more info check `help selection`.